# Let's populate our chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

I recently went over to the [Code Review beta site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and for some reason felt inclined to join one of their chat rooms.

Over the time I have chatted with them, I have learned a lot about the community over there, and feel that the chat experience is a huge part of acquiring a larger core community.  I also believe that it will bring about a movement that will eventually help this site graduate.

[The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) is a [very quiet place these days](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12586277#12586277). I want to change that, so I will be making it a habit to try and visit there every day.  Hopefully I will see some of you over there at some point in time.

Comment: I have seen mentions of a chat room on the Raspberry Pi beta site, but have no idea where it may be. How do you expect new users to find it? There is no link on the site that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Genealogy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/) Beta Site has a system of proposing a "Chat Topic of the Week".  The topic being posted on the Meta site a few days beforehand.  That gets people into the chat rooms.

Could we do something similar?  For example Camera week, GPIO week, WiFi week, and so on.

Comment: I like this idea.  Just as long as the room is not governed by this topic (if the topic goes on a tangent, I am fine with that).

Comment: Indeed.  The topic should be a means of breaking the ice, not to shut out other topics.

Comment: Would any moderators like to support this idea?

Comment: @syb0rg Yes yes yes!  I love this idea.

Comment: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/432/20

Comment: Honestly I dont think this will help getting it populated.