# Topic of the Week in the Chat room: First Time Raspberry Pi Usage

Tags: discussion, chat

## Week 1 Topic: First Time Raspberry Pi Usage

In the interest of making the chat room a more popular place to talk, we're going to start having a topic of the week [as suggested in another meta question](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/430/20).  While other topics will still be discussed, topic of the week will serve as sort of an ice breaker.

Week 1 has been decided.  Votes are now open for Week 2.

What should our topic be for next week (beginning 12/29) be?  Answer/vote below.

Comment: This should be `featured` so that more people can see this.

Comment: @syb0rg Good call

Comment: How do I access the chatroom plz?

Comment: It's here: [chat]

Answer (score 3):

### Topic Ideas

I didn't want to post all of these as separate answers, if you really like one just say so in the comments and we can upvote it there.  Feel free to add topics to the list as well.

- First time Raspberry Pi usage
- Creating a web server
- Must-have software/tools
- Best cases/accessories
- Best games
- Learning how to program
- Optimising a media player
- Home automation

Comment: First time Raspberry Pi usage

Comment: Creating a web server

Comment: Learning how to program

Comment: Must-have software/tools

Comment: home automation